# JavaScript not working inside form

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML code

```
   <div class = "login">
        <form>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" style="text-align:center"> <br> <br>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" style="text-align:center"> <br> <br>
        <input  onclick="loginButton();" name="login_btn" id="login_btn" type="submit"  value="Login">
        </form>
   </div>
```

And the following JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loginButton() {
        console.log("this function was called")
    }
</script>
```

In my console, when I click the submit button, "this function was called" appears for only a brief second, and then disappears. Yet when I put the submit button outside of the form, the message stays, and fully executes the rest of my function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i stop the form from reloading using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150532/how-do-i-stop-the-form-from-reloading-using-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your form gets submitted and the page reloads - because of `type="submit"` on `input` element.

Change it either to

`type="button"`

or

`onclick="loginButton(); return false;"`

Comment: But inside form without submit button I think not possible.

Comment: @AkramKhan - I don't understand your sentence, try rephrasing.

Comment: I am saying if you are submiting a form without jquery/ajax then you must must be use submit button